# R convert imported Excel numeric back from R factors to numeric

Tags: r, excel, import, statistics

I'm trying to read an Excel created .csv file into R. I've tried numerous suggestions but none have completely panned out for me.

Here's how the data looks in the .csv file, with the first row being the header:

```
recipe_type,State,Successes,Attempts
paper,alabama ,586,3379
```

Here are my R commands to import the .csv file:

```
options( StringsAsFactors=F )
results<-read.csv("recipe results.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=T)
results$Successes
[1] "586"
```

And Successes is being treated as character data.

And I've also tried this approach:
results[,3]<- as.numeric(levels(results$Successes)) but get the rank of each value in this column rather than the actual value, which another posts said would happen.

Any ideas on how to get this data treated as numeric so I can get proper stat.desc stats for it?

Thanks

Comment: To convert factor to numeric you can use `as.numeric(results$Successes)`. But it seems that there are some non-numeric values in that column.

Comment: Hi DrDom: Do you mean like this: results<-as.numeric(results$Successes)? I got all: [1] NA NA NA NA. Previously, I think I got the rank values when using the as.numeric.

Comment: DrDom, that is incorrect.  You need to convert to character, then to numeric.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, I know, but it seems that the third column should be of character, numeric or interger type according to option `as.is=T`.

Comment: @Jazzmine, your example works for me. Look at class of your variables by calling `sapply(results, class)`

Comment: @Jazzmine please re-read the file in and then paste the output from `str(results)` and also from `dput( head( results ) )`, this will help us understand the problem a bit better.

Comment: The name of the option is misspelled. Try: `grep("StringsAsFactors", names(options()) )`. That may or may not be part of the problem. The other part could be that "T" and is not a reserved word and you should be using `TRUE` and `FALSE` for logical constants.

Answer (score 3):

Direct conversion of a factor to numeric yields the factor levels, and nothing to do with the values themselves.  You need to convert to character first:

```
results[,3] <- as.numeric(as.character(results$Successes))
```

Equivalently (see `?factor`), you can convert the levels to numeric, and index by the (implicit) numeric conversion of the factor.

```
as.numeric(levels(results$Successes))[results$Successes]
```

Comment: According to the options the OP set, `results$Successes` should not be of type factor? Please can you explain why it is converted to factor when `as.is=T` and `stringsAsFactors=F`?

Comment: Matthew, your first command above yielded this:Error in results$Successes : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Comment: @Jazzmine are you sure you do not have a matrix? What is the output of `class(results)`?

Comment: So this may be the problem, in that it is not a data.frame?

Comment: Yes, it can be the problem. But according to the given code `result` should be a `data.frame`. Look carefully in you actual code. The problem is there.

Answer (score 2):

Realise this is an old question, but came across it today when having a similar issue. 
I Eventually found that (in my case) the problem arose from Excel's 'Number' format includes a comma (,) in its values so: 1,000 instead of 1000. Once I removed the comma I was able to convert from factors without NA values.

```
df$col1 <-as.numeric(gsub(",","",df$col1))
```

Just in case anyone comes across something simialr.

Answer (score 0):

I found this package to be most helpful, worked without any issues, aside from a warning: gdata.

This URL contains the info on the package:http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import

I did convert my spreadsheet from an .xlsx to .xls which it seemed to expect. I didn't test if  an .xlsx would work.